# System.io.exception file already exists

Tags: asp.net

In a .net application, I did a text export from grid view.

Before saving that textfile I want to delete the file if already exists in the folder.

First time the textfile was exported. On the second time of textfile generation, excel file was not able to delete and shows the error as:

> `System.IO.IOException`: The process cannot access the file `'F:\Test\\report.txt'` because it is being used by another process.

And also I was not able to delete the excel manually, that time an error was thrown as:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in `webdev.webserver.exe`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code with us

Comment: You're keeping the file locked in your own code. You're forgetting to close or dispose a stream somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

delete the file in try catch block before creating. and handle the exception accordingly

Comment: The solution to "I get an exception when I do X" is not "Put X in a try-catch clause". You also cannot "handle" this particular exception. You must prevent it.